# Spawning multiple maven builds of same module simultaneously

Tags: maven

When I execute mvn clean install, I need to spawn the same command on the same project multiple times.
I mean, If I execute mvn clean install once, it should start n number of simultaneous builds of the project in n different command windows, where n should be user configurable.
I know we can use multi module project to simultaneously build different related projects together. But I need to build the same project simultaneously n number of times. any idea?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this kind of thing? Apart from that it is not safe to run simultaneous build with the same local repository.

Comment: I need to run the build on n number of different database schemas. (maybe upto 10). I can use teamcity to do execute the builds, so that builds can run simultaneously without disturbing each other.

Comment: Is it to run tests on different databases or to build different distributions ?

Comment: to run tests on different db schemas simultaneously

Comment: Test must really have to be simultaneous ? how is your schema configured in your app ?

Comment: I use unitils framework. So each test class will have its own dataset. Before my integration test starts, db schema is cleared of all the existing data. This is done by a dependency added to the pre integration test phase. This clears only one schema. Now I want to use multiple schemas while running integration tests, so that my tests can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Your could make your database connection configurable by Maven:

in your unitils.properties

```
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@yourmachine:1521:YOUR_DB
database.userName=john
database.password=secret
database.schemaNames=${database.schemaNames}
```

Activates maven filter on your resources, in your pom.xml:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

you can provide a default value for your schema

```
<properties>
    <database.schemaNames>testschema1</database.schemaNames>
</properties>
```

Once this done, you can configure your schema directly from the command lines :

```
mvn test -Ddatabase.schemaNames=testschema2
```

You can finally configure multiple jobs in your teamcity to run your test on different schemas.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hugo. I almost have similar config in my pom. configuring multiple jobs manually in team city is the only option? What I wanted is, user fire the mvn clean install command once and that trigger multiple build, each working on different db schemas.

Comment: That the simplest way I see.